# C# generic supertype wildcard

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard

I got a problem with wildcards in generics in C#. First approach to get my little example running was to use object as generic type because it is the base class of everything.

```
   public class AttributeManager
    {

        private Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<object>> attributes = new Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<object>>();

        public void add(AttributeItem<object> attribute)
        {
            if (hasAttribute(attribute)) {
                return;
            }
            attributes.Add(attribute.getKey(), attribute);
        }
    }

public abstract class AttributeItem<T>
{
    private int key;
    private T attributeValue;
    private AttributeManager attributeManager;

    public AttributeItem(AttributeManager attributeManager, int key)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.attributeManager = attributeManager;
        attributeManager.add(this); // this line does not work
    }

    public void setValue(T newValue)
    {
        attributeValue = newValue;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return attributeValue;
    }
}
```

However, the line:

> attributeManager.add(this);

does not work. It says there was no overloaded method found for this call. I thought that "this" will get casted to AttributeItem because object must be superclass of T.
So my first question is why does this cast does not work?

My second approach was to change the AttributeManager to use kind of wildcards:

```
   public class AttributeManager
    {

        private Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<????>> attributes = new Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<????>>();

        /**
         * This method will add a new AttributeItem if hasAttribute(AttributeItem) returns false.
         */
        public void add<T>(AttributeItem<T> attribute)
        {
            if (hasAttribute(attribute)) {
                return;
            }
            attributes.Add(attribute.getKey(), attribute); // this line fails
        }

    }
```

But as you can see, I have no clue what type I have to pass in the declaration:

```
Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<????>> attributes
```

So my second question is, what do I have to use instead of ?????

Regards
Robert

Comment: Ah yes I had the same issue when designing a solution, I personally ended up redesigning it. I imagine you are trying to avoid <T> being on the class declaration AttributeManager?

Comment: Yes right. I dont want it to be generic too. I want it to accept any kind of attributes.

Comment: You can use an interface instead and change your AttributeItem so that it has where T : YourInterface constraint? So code will look like private Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<YourInterface>> attributes = new Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<YourInterface>>();

Comment: Perhaps it would help to state, or think about how you want to use the generic attributes dictionary other than just "add".  As currently stated, since you don't do anything but add, you could just as easily have a Dictionary<int,object>

Comment: Agree with above. My solution probably over complicates things however will give you this generic "feel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is to get rid of generics at the level of your private dictionary field:

```
private Dictionary<int, object> attributes = new Dictionary<int, object>();
```

That way your class still has a nice generic interface and you don't need to have a generic Manager instance.

The difficult part is getting something useful out of the dictionary later on. You could use reflection, but I suggest you use the interface technique as suggested by Onam and Robert Hahn. Tell us more about your usecase, if this does not solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
public class AttributeManager<T>
{

    private Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<T>> attributes = new Dictionary<int, AttributeItem<T>>();

    public void add(AttributeItem<T> attribute)
    {
        if (hasAttribute(attribute)) {
            return;
        }
        attributes.Add(attribute.getKey(), attribute);
    }

}
```

Comment: But than my AttributeManager is generic too. But I want it to accept any kind of Attributes. I forgot that to mention.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the line:
>
> attributeManager.add(this);
>
> does not work. It says there was no overloaded method found for this call. I thought that > "this" will get casted to AttributeItem because object must be superclass of T

You need to read about [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). Basically, just because `T` is convertible to a base type doesn't meant a generic interface is. It all depends on *what* the interface is used for.

In your case, T is an input parameter, so it cannot be contravariant (enabling the AttributeItem cast). Otherwise, the compile-time contract would allow object to be passed to setValue, which is not a valid substitution.

Depending on what you need to *do* with AttributeItem, you may be able to define a contravariant interface with just the needed generic return values for AttributeManager.